# 'Cannot read property 'hasError' of null' in Angular(v6) forms

Tags: angular, angular6

While creating the reactive form using material components in Angular (v6), i get error

> Cannot read property 'hasError' of null.

**component.ts**

```
categoryGroup = new FormGroup({
name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]),
overview: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
});
```

**componnet.html**

```
<form class="example-container" [style.fontSize.px]="16" [formGroup]="categoryGroup" #addCategoryForm="ngForm">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <input matInput 
            name="Name"
            placeholder="name" 
            formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="formField">
    <textarea matInput 
                placeholder="desc" 
                rows="5" 
                formControlName="overview"></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Where you are calling `.hasError()`?

Comment: `[formGroup]="categoryGroup" #addCategoryForm="ngForm"` : chose only one, template driven or reactive, but not both.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT yes. forgot to add here...

Comment: @trichetriche thanks for updating. will check that from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. ensure the name of field in `formControlName` of component.html is same as name defined in `categoryGroup` of component.ts.
2. define [getters](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-3-accessing-the-formarray-control) in component.ts as

```js
get name() { return this.categoryGroup.get('name');  }
get overview() { return this.categoryGroup.get('overview');  }
```